Starting a new page using PNAS template
I am using the PNAS template. I am trying to start a new page before my supplementary materials, but using \newpage or \pagebreak seems to confuse the template.
I get several unhelpful errors such as: "You can't use `\char"F4' after \advance", "Missing number, treated as zero.", "LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.". I have confirmed the casue of the errors is \newpage since errors dissappear and everything compiles fine if I remove it.
Is there a way to fix this or is there an alternative way I can achieve a page break?

Welcome! Can you provide code for a minimal document we can compile to reproduce the error? Please also post the exact text of the first error message. This should include the context and line number, though sometimes this is a guess and not always actually where the problem is.

presumably you have put \newpage in a place where it causes errors but as you have not shown where, and only given a fragment of the error message it is hard to help.

Is PNAS a common class file?

@cfr Sorry for insufficient info. It's my first time asking a question here. As suggested by you guys, I tried to generate a minimal document to reproduce the error, but somehow the error got fixed on the original document. Now I'm extremely confused but happy that it got fixed. Thanks for your help!

Using the Template for preparing your research report submission to PNAS using Overleaf (2023)
After the Acknowledgments section and before the Bibliography, add your supplemental section by issuing \vfill\eject\clearpage before it, to start a new page:
     ...

\showacknow{} % Display the acknowledgments section

%************************************************
\vfill\eject\clearpage %<<<<<<<<<<<<

\section{Suplementary Material} 
\lipsum[1-2] % added \usepackage{lipsum} before \begin{document}
%***********************************************

\bibsplit[2]

% Bibliography
\bibliography{pnas-sample}

\end{document}



The issue is fixed now, but this seems like the appropriate way to do what I was looking for. Thank you!
